# Angular and Firebase app won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
    <!-- anything typed in here is magically saved to Firebase! -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.text"/>

    <!-- all changes from Firebase magically appear here! -->
    <h1>You said: {{ data.text }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my app.js file:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])

app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-inferno-4208.firebaseio.com/data");
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);

  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
});

})();
```

I copied it from this example: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

When I try to run it on my own computer, I get these errors in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

I can't figure out what's wrong!

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` means that there is a typo in your script somewhere. I can't see it in this example. But in the inspector click on that error messages line number to find it. The next error is just a following error to this first one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo / non-reproducible, as your code doesn't even match the example you have taken it from.  Before posting a question, you should closely inspect your code.  You have incorrectly tried to turn a standard function into an IIFE, which the example did not do.

Comment: Hi same issue here. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Your module isn't being loaded because the function you create is never executed. Looks like you are missing `()` right before the final `;` in your script. This fixes it for me:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])

    app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-inferno-4208.firebaseio.com/data");
        var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);

        syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
    });

})();
```

Comment: Bingo. Should have been caught with the debugger and never made it to SO.

Comment: Thanks this was a good catch, but I'm still getting: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Answer (score 0):

$injector:modulerr basically means the module failed to load, could be a number of things.

```js
<script>
      var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);

      myApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",
        function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
          //CREATE A FIREBASE REFERENCE
          var ref = new Firebase("https://qst13ns0z14.firebaseio-demo.com/");

          // GET MESSAGES AS AN ARRAY
          $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);

          //ADD MESSAGE METHOD
          $scope.addMessage = function(e) {

            //LISTEN FOR RETURN KEY
            if (e.keyCode === 13 && $scope.msg) {
              //ALLOW CUSTOM OR ANONYMOUS USER NAMES
              var name = $scope.name || "anonymous";

              //ADD TO FIREBASE
              $scope.messages.$add({
                from: name,
                body: $scope.msg
              });

              //RESET MESSAGE
              $scope.msg = "";
            }
          }
        }
      ]);
    </script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/tutorial/css/example.css"/>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyController">

    <!-- CHAT MARKUP -->
    <div class="example-chat l-demo-container">
      <header>Firebase Chat Demo</header>

      <div class="example-chat-toolbar">
        <label for="nameInput">Username:</label>
        <input ng-model="name" type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="enter a username...">
      </div>

      <ul id="example-messages" class="example-chat-messages">
        <li ng-repeat="msg in messages">
          <strong class="example-chat-username">{{ msg.from }}</strong>
          {{ msg.body }}
        </li>
      </ul>

      <footer>
        <input ng-model="msg" ng-keydown="addMessage($event)" type="text" id="messageInput"  placeholder="Type a message...">
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```